# Spatial join two identical layers

Tags: python, geopandas, spatial-join

I'm working with Python and GeoPandas. I have two parcel layers that are identical and in the same coordinate reference system. The parcel number field is not unique so I am unable to join on that field. I performed a spatial join but this produced undesirable results.

```
sjoin_parcels = gpd.sjoin(parcels_2021, parcels_2020, how='inner', op='intersects')
```

There are about 600,000 parcels in the data set but `sjoin_parcels` has 1.9 million records. I thought about converting one layer to points and using the centroid to perform the join but am concerned about irregular polygons and their centroid not being in the polygon. Based on their description [here](https://geopandas.org/mergingdata.html), `within` and `contains` do not seem to be the right solution either. Is there a way to perform the join so that it joins features that are coincident?

I've also tried a merge on the `geometry` attribute but that returned an empty dataframe.

Comment: If you know their geometries are identical, then you know that a label point for one will be inside the other. That's likely to be a faster join.

Comment: If `sjoin_parcels` contains three times as many records, then the layers are probably not identical, but one a geometry in one layer intersects with more than one geometry in the other layer.

Comment: Could you provide sample datasets with only a few features that exhibit the behavior you describe?

Answer (score 1):

You can join by [representative_point](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.representative_point.html):

> ...points that are guaranteed to be within each geometry.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

con = create_engine("postgresql://postgres@localhost/data")
sql = "select fid as id, geom from lmv.sankmark"
df = gpd.read_postgis(sql=sql, con=con)
print(df.shape)
#(747771, 2)

#I'm joining the layer to itself
df2 = df.copy()
df2 = df2.set_geometry(df2.representative_point()) #Set the geometry to a point

#Plot a subset
ymin, xmin = 6724312.5,457114.1
ymax, xmax = 6729930.1,461730.1
ax = df.cx[xmin:xmax, ymin:ymax].plot(figsize=(20,20), column="id", cmap="ocean")#color="lightgreen")
df2.cx[xmin:xmax, ymin:ymax].plot(ax=ax, color="red", markersize=100)

#Join
sj = gpd.sjoin(left_df=df, right_df=df2, 
                predicate="intersects", how="left")
```

[image]